# How to replace a join with subquery and cte?

Tags: sql-server, subquery, inner-join

Hello i'm practicing multi options for each question I solve.
I want to transform this query with join into a query with subqueries and another query with cte.

however I'm finding it hard to do so:

```
SELECT 
    C.CompanyName, MAX(OD.UnitPrice*OD.Quantity)MaxOdPrice, 
    MIN(OD.UNITPRICE*OD.Quantity) MinOdPrice
FROM [Order Details] OD 
JOIN Orders O       ON OD.OrderID=O.OrderID
JOIN Customers C    ON O.CustomerID=C.CustomerID
GROUP BY C.CompanyName
```

thanks

Comment: Well, you're still going to need joins... are you trying to recreate this query entirely without use of JOIN keyword? (ansi-89 doesn't count)

Comment: I understand and appreciate trying different approaches and applaud you for wanting to try different things. But it is not at all clear what you want to do here. If you are just wanting practice with ctes and such there are better ways to learn them instead of just throwing random requirements at a solution.

Comment: You are selecting from different tables.  How do you expect to replace `JOIN`s with subqueries?

Answer (score 0):

You will still need JOINS but here's a simplistic CTE that I hope may give some ideas on how to proceed further

```
;With cteCustomers
AS(
    SELECT  X.CustomerID, X.CompanyName
    FROM    Customers X
)
SELECT 
    C.CompanyName, MAX(OD.UnitPrice*OD.Quantity)MaxOdPrice, 
    MIN(OD.UNITPRICE*OD.Quantity) MinOdPrice
FROM [Order Details]    OD 
JOIN Orders             O   ON  OD.OrderID=O.OrderID
JOIN cteCustomers       C   ON  O.CustomerID=C.CustomerID
GROUP BY C.CompanyName
```

Answer (score 0):

**completely untested** but I think something like this can do it without joins.

```
select C.CompanyName,
   max(select MAX(UnitPrice * Quantity)
       from [Order Details]
       where OrderID in (select distinct OrderID
                         from Orders
                         where CustomerID in (select CustomerID
                                              from Customers innerC
                                              where innerC.CompanyName = C.CompanyName
                                             )
                       )
       group by OrderID
      ) AS MaxOdPrice
FROM Customers C
GROUP BY C.CompanyName
```

I'm only showing MaxOdPrice.